# undefined error in ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

After selecting the date I am getting undefined error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

My html code

```
<ion-datetime name="fromdate" id="today1" ></ion-datetime>

<button ion-button full (click)="check()">Submit</button>
```

My script

```
check() {
      alert(document.getElementById("today1").value);
}
```

Comment: show complete error logs

Comment: why manipulate DOM to get the value?

Comment: I mean after selecting the date and clicking the Submit button I am getting undefined.

Comment: I am not getting error logs.

Comment: @BoidurjaTalukdar check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind your input with `ngModel` and get the value you selected like this -

```
  <ion-datetime name="fromdate" id="today1" displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
  <button ion-button full (click)="check()">Submit</button>


  check() {
      alert(this.myDate);
  }
```

## [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-mp6vtx?file=pages%2Fabout%2Fabout.ts)

No need to get Value using DOM selector's like you did when there is option provided by ionic to get value.

Comment: I am still getting undefined in alertbox.

Comment: Now I am getting StoredetailsPage.html:107 ERROR TypeError: _co.check is not a function

Comment: THere must be error somewhere else as I already shared a working link for the same

Comment: Thanks. I did not see myDate: any;